# Simplify $(x^3+x-1)(x^2+x+1)-(x-1)(x^4+x^2+1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify $$A(x)=(x^3+x-1)(x^2+x+1)-(x-1)(x^4+x^2+1)$$
Is there something clever that we can do/notice here? E.g. in the first bracket $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$. The second term is the same as the second term in $A(x)$. Thank you! I don't see anything else.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+%28x%5E3%2Bx-1%29*%28x%5E2%2Bx%2B1%29+-+%28x-1%29*%28x%5E4%2Bx%5E2%2B1%29)

Comment: @DietrichBurde, everything or just the first two terms?

Comment: Don't multiply everything out when it is clear that $x^2+x+1$ divides $x^4+x^2+1$ (think nonreal cube- and sixth-roots of unity).

Answer (score 2):

Alt. hint: $\,x^4+x^2+1\color{red}{+x^2-x^2}=\left(x^2+1\right)^2-x^2=\left(x^2+x+1\right)\left(x^2-x+1\right)\,$, then $\,x^2+x+1\,$ factors out.

Answer (score 0):

Even just multiplying out gives directly
$x(2x^3 + x^2 + x - 1)$, which factorises then as
$$
(x^2 + x + 1)(2x - 1)x.
$$
The last step can be seen from the rational root theorem, which yields the factor $2x-1$.